# React Native FlatList not showing the last message in a real time chat app

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I am trying to make a real-time chat app using react native.
Here is the problem I have.
Ideally, when a new message is sent, the message list should scroll up a little to show the new message just like other famous chat apps do. However my situation is this, the list is one message lag behind. Say the message at the list bottom is 'hello', when I send another message 'world', the new message 'world' doesn't show. The message 'hello' is still at the bottom. When I send another message 'why', the list scroll up and the message 'world' appear. But the message 'why' is still not visible. When I scroll the list manually, the last message appears.

Here is the code:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
const flatListRef = useRef()

const scrollUp = () => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd()

useEffect(fetchMessages)
useEffect( scrollUp, [messages])

<FlatList
  ref={flatListRef}
  …
>
```

Anyone can tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show ```fetchMessages``` method? How does it update the messages?

Comment: You can work with onLayout prop and scroll to bottom there

Comment: @ Arbnor Could you show me how to do it? It seems that FlatList doesn't have an onLayout prop. Thanks.